# Convert from numpy.timedelta64 to time interval

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm having a hard time converting `numpy.timedelta64`, which is directional, into a time span, which is not directional. I don't see any instructions [in the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.datetime.html)

The `.abs` function does not seem to work on timedelta values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.abs(x)` or `abs(x)`, both work fine.